# How to nest data in PHP array and access it with foreach()?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, navbar

```
foreach ($nav_items as $nav_href=>$nav_title=>$nav_class) {
    if ($pageHref == $nav_href) {
        echo '<li class="' . $nav_class .  'active">' . $nav_title . '</li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li class="' . $nav_class . '">' . $nav_title . '</li>';
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code above? This corresponds to the array below.

```
$pageLoc = 'where';
$nav_items = array(
    'index'=>'Home'==>'', 
    'where'=>'Where?'==>'dropdown'==>'', 
    'appeals'=>'Current Appeals'==>'', 
    'news'=>'Latest News'==>'', 
    'events'=>'Events'==>'', 
    'dontate'=>'Dontate'==>'', 
);
```

I am basically trying to put an active class in front of the list item when it matches `$pageLoc` and when it doesn't just a simple `<li class="">` BUT the dropdown menu item: `'where?'` needs a `<li class="dropdown">` always! and when it is active, it will be `<li class="dropdown active">`

Comment: You need to use nested arrays for this

Comment: all you'd need to do to figure out this won't work is ... run the code. you'll get an error that tells you exactly what's wrong (your syntax, in this case).

Answer (score 2):

You have a flat-out syntax error:

```
foreach ($nav_items as $nav_href=>$nav_title=>$nav_class) {
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The syntax is

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
```

You cannot have `=> $value1 => $value2 etc...`.

Comment: Any ideas on how to go about solving my issue? I have a menu with active classes. But for one menu item, I need a dropdown class always to preside there.

Comment: `$nav_href=>$nav_title` in your foreach, then grab them from within the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You ca n have it as :

foreach ($nav_items as $nav_title=>$nav_class) {

```
  ....
```

}

What are you trying to check with $nav_href ?

Comment: It is for a navbar menu. So they all have normal <li></li>. When on that page, eg when $nav_href= 'current-page' the li class for that menu item will be 'active' and the others remain at <li>. My problem is, I have one menu item that requires a dropdown class always.

Comment: Why dont you check this way ? if($pageLoc == $nav_class) because your $nav_class is the key in the key-value pair, and as seen from your array, 'where' appears to be the key.

Answer (score 0):

your `$nav_items` is a pretty mess, not a correct array.

```
$pageLoc = 'where';
$nav_items = array('index'=>'Home==>', 'where'=>'Where?==>', 'appeals'=>'Current Appeals==>', 'news'=>'Latest News==>', 'events'=>'Events==>', 'dontate'=>'Dontate==>');


foreach ($nav_items as $nav_class=>$nav_title) {
   if ($pageLoc == $nav_href) {
         echo '<li class="' . $nav_class .  'active">' . $nav_title . '</li>';
   } 
   else {
       echo '<li class="' . $nav_class . '">' . $nav_title . '</li>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such syntax that makes it that easy.
But here is what you probably want:

This is how you create a *nested array* which fits your needs:

```
$nav_items = array(
    array('href' => 'index',   'title' => 'Home',            'class' => ''), 
    array('href' => 'where',   'title' => 'Where?',          'class' => 'dropdown'), 
    array('href' => 'appeals', 'title' => 'Current Appeals', 'class' => ''), 
    array('href' => 'news',    'title' => 'Latest News',     'class' => ''), 
    array('href' => 'events',  'title' => 'Events',          'class' => ''), 
    array('href' => 'dontate', 'title' => 'Dontate',         'class' => ''),                
);
```

According to the above array structure this would be the `foreach` for you to use:

```
foreach ($nav_items as $item) {
    if ($pageHref == $item['href']) {
        echo '<li class="' . $item['class'] .  ' active">' . $item['title'] . '</li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li class="' . $item['class'] . '">' . $item['title'] . '</li>';
    }
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qip-2cc)

**Here is 2 more notes:**

*Note1:* In [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) you could work with objects and create a nav item class containing the information which is above only the simple `array('href' => 'dontate', 'title' => 'Dontate', 'class' => '')`

*Note2:* 
Your line

```
echo '<li class="' . $nav_class .  'active">' . $nav_title . '</li>';
```

will concatenate both classes to one. So this code would give you `dropdownactive` as the class. You need to insert a space before active, else CSS won't recognize both classes.